# jQuery Multiple conditionals with isNumeric

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is with a couple of things.

1. Whether having `if` statements inside of `if` statements is a bad thing.
2. If there is a better way to condense my code so I'm not chaining a bunch of logical operators chained together.

Also I can't figure out why my `isNumeric` is not working, I've got a really simple 
form with a couple of input boxes and I'm looping around them in my
jquery. What happens is I can input a string of letters that is > 5 and it won't
hit the `isNumeric` conditional. Ideally a user has to enter numbers for this.
Any ideas?

```
$("form :input").each(function(){

if(this.id = "zipCode" && $(this).val().length < 5 && $(this).is(":visible")){
 if($.isNumeric($(this).val())){
     //do something
 }
}
});
```

Comment: For a) and b): If you're the only person to work with that code, you should settle with what __you__ feel comfortable with. Try a few things and settle on a style. When you work with others, adhere to the rules that the majority sets. Shorter is not always better, though. Readability is king.

Comment: For a) and b) I agree with Delmon Young. Anyway, have you tried using `!isNaN` instead of `$.isNumeric`? If it is not what you're looking for, please post a fiddle so that we have more informations to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a wrong parameter to the `isNumeric` function. This line

```
if($.isNumeric($(this.val())){
```

should be

```
if($.isNumeric($(this).val())){
```

As for the long list of conditionals, you can refactor them into a separate function with a name that reflects its purpose. In this case for example, you could create a function like this:

```
function isValidZipcode(field) {
    return field.id = "zipCode" && 
           $(field).val().length < 5 && 
           $(field).is(":visible");
}
```

Then it looks cleaner like this:

```
if(isValidZipcode(this)){
    if($.isNumeric($(this).val())){
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Except sorry that was a typo in my code I actually had $(this) not $(thi and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the advise on creating a separate function.